# Task.WhenAny with cancellation of the non completed tasks and timeout

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

In my app I am creating some concurrent web requests and I am satisfied when any one of them completes, so I am using the method [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany):

```
var urls = new string[] {
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    "https://superuser.com",
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/chess",
};
var tasks = urls.Select(async url =>
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        return (Url: url, Data: await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url));
    }
}).ToArray();
var firstTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
Console.WriteLine($"First Completed Url: {firstTask.Result.Url}");
Console.WriteLine($"Data: {firstTask.Result.Data.Length:#,0} chars");
```

> First Completed Url: https://superuser.com
>   Data: 121.954 chars

What I don't like to this implementation is that the non-completed tasks continue downloading data I no longer need, and waste bandwidth I would prefer to preserve for my next batch of requests. So I am thinking about cancelling the other tasks, but I am not sure how to do it. I found how to use a `CancellationToken` to cancel a specific web request:

```
public static async Task<(string Url, string Data)> DownloadUrl(
    string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            cancellationToken.Register(webClient.CancelAsync);
            return (url, await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url));
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex) when (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Now I need an implementation of `Task.WhenAny` that will take an array of urls, and will use my `DownloadUrl` function to fetch the data of the fastest responding site, and will handle the cancellation logic of the slower tasks. It would be nice if it had a **timeout** argument, to offer protection against never-ending tasks. So I need something like this:

```
public static Task<Task<TResult>> WhenAnyEx<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> taskFactory,
    int timeout)
{
    // What to do here?
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply pass to all of your tasks the same cancellation token, something like this:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
// here you specify how long you want to wait for task to finish before cancelling
int timeout = 5000;
cts.CancelAfter(timeout);
// pass ct to all your tasks and start them
await Task.WhenAny(/* your tasks here */);
// cancel all tasks
cts.Cancel();
```

Also, you need to read this thread to be aware of how to use `CancellationToken` correctly: [When I use CancelAfter(), the Task is still running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971316/when-i-use-cancelafter-the-task-is-still-running)

Comment: That's the gist of it, but WebClient does not support it directly, you need the *ct.Register(webClient.CancelAsync);* too to make the downloads stop.

Comment: @JakubFojtik Did you read OP's code? It's enough to pass token to a task, inside it it will register it, as you suggest :)

Comment: Simple and effective! 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it has helped you :)

Comment: Michał I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer, for the case that someone offers a complete solution with timeout. 

Comment: Simple and effective again! 

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: better solution based on [Stephen Cleary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10134604/1333247) and [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netframework-4.8) and [svick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798539/how-to-attach-cancellationtokensource-to-downloadstringtaskasync-method-and-canc):

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

var tasks = urls.Select(url => Task.Run( async () => 
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        token.Register(webClient.CancelAsync);
        var result = (Url: url, Data: await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url));
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return result.Url;
    }
}, token)).ToArray();

string url;
try
{
    // (A canceled task will raise an exception when awaited).
    var firstTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    url = (await firstTask).Url;
}   
catch (AggregateException ae) {
   foreach (Exception e in ae.InnerExceptions) {
      if (e is TaskCanceledException)
         Console.WriteLine("Timeout: {0}", 
                           ((TaskCanceledException) e).Message);
      else
         Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.GetType().Name);
   }
}
```

---

**non-optimal solution**

The timeout can be solved by adding a task that just waits and completes after given time. Then you check which task completed first, if it is the waiting one, then timeout effectively occurred.

```
Task timeout = Task.Delay(10000);
var firstTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks.Concat(new Task[] {timeout}));
if(firstTask == timeout) { ... } //timed out
source.Cancel();
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. The non completed tasks will continue running in the background. I want to cancel these tasks, to preserve bandwidth.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Sorry, see edit, now it should work.

Comment: Jakub I tested your updated code, made some changes to overpass some compilation errors, and unfortunately it's not doing what I want. The non-completed tasks continue running. I want them `Canceled`, not `RanToCompletion`. I would also prefer I generalized solution that I could apply to different scenarios. See the signature of `WhenAnyEx` that is included in my question.

Comment: 'A canceled task will raise an exception when awaited' is not true.  You're awaiting it twice in your try statement, and the second await will throw an exception, but I don't recommend awaiting a task twice.

Comment: LINQ's [`Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.8) is slightly better than `Concat` here.